# Can a PC Necromancer maintain undead with the Animate Dead spell if they were originally raised with the Danse Macabre spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, undead, necromancy

Since the casting time of Danse Macabre is more favourable to a higher level Necromancer, it would be more efficient to raise undead with Dance Macabre and then maintain them with Animate Dead. Is this rules-legal?

[Danse Macabre](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/danse-macabre) is a 5th-level spell with casting time of 1 action; raises undead (Up to 5 Zombies or Skeletons).

[Animate Dead](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-dead) is a 3rd-level spell with casting time of 1 minute; maintains raised undead (Raise 1 Zombie or Skeleton, or maintain up to 4 Zombies or Skeletons for 24 hours).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### No, you cannot use *animate dead* this way

In the spell description for [*animate dead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-dead) (PHB 213, emphasis mine), we read that:

> This use of the spell reasserts your control over up to four creatures
>   you have animated **with this spell**

Thus it cannot be used to maintain control on undead created by other spells.